# I hold a string '484792' length but i can't use all characters of this string

Tags: javascript, string

There is I have a function

```
function DisplayPDF(varData) {

  console.log(varData.length) // 484792
  window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + varData);

}
```

when i get this varData to `windows.open()` it doen't replace all string in here.

Comment: You’re probably hitting the maximum length of a URL your browser allows.

Comment: @deceze maybe but how can i fix it

Comment: You cannot "fix" it, you should rethink your current solution entirely

Comment: @zerkms Thank you for your suggestion. hopefully find another solution